# assign a value from a foreach loop to an asp:button CommandArgument

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code behind file creates a list of employees and the asp.net page loops through list.
Now, How do I assign the employeedID to the commandArgument of an asp:button?

```
  <%foreach(var employee in employeesList){%>
    <tr>
     <td><%=employee.firstName%></td>
     <td><%=employee.lastName%></td>
    /*How to access employee.Id in the commandArgument? */
    <td><asp:Button ID="btnDeleteEmployee" runat="server" CommandArgument=''    Text="Delete" OnCommand="btnDeleteEmployee_Click" /></td>
    </tr>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Is this MVC code or WebForms?

Comment: It's webforms.Please see my comment for Aaron's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is a nested example:

**Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptOutter" 
    onitemdatabound="rptOutter_ItemDataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("firstName") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("lastName") %></td>
            <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteEmployee" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Text="Delete" OnCommand="btnDeleteEmployee_Click"  /></td>
            <td>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptInner" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>                                
                            <tr>
                                <td><%#Eval("firstNameInner") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("lastNameInner") %></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        rptOutter.DataSource = outterDataSource;
        rptOutter.DataBind();
    }

}

protected void rptOutter_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
        (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        //get your datasource from parent repeater if needed
        //cast to your datasource type
        //DataSourceObject ds = (DataSourceObject)item.DataItem;
        Repeater r = e.Item.FindControl("rptInner") as Repeater;
        if (r != null)
        {
            r.DataSource = innerDataSource;
            r.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad I saw this before posting almost exactly the same thing!

Comment: Thank you Rick. That worked.copy/paste issue in the code.Should be:
if(r!=null){
r.DataSource = innerDataSource;
r.DataBind();
}

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptEmployeeList">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("firstName") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("lastName") %></td>
            <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeleteEmployee" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Text="Delete" OnCommand="btnDeleteEmployee_Click"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and then in the codebehind

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    rptEmployeeList.DataSource = employeeList;
    rptEmployeeList.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible using the foreach loop, because in this case , I need a nested for loop to go through the projects that the employee is working on (an example). Or alternately, Can I have a nested asp:Repeater ?

Comment: _rick_schott has a nested example